# Else statement being executed after if statement is satisfied

Tags: java, android, if-statement, andengine

I am using AndEngine to develop my game, though I'm thinking this problem is unrelated to AndEngine.

I have two possible dialogs that fire if:

1. User touches down in an incorrect area or
2. Users lifts up from an incorrect area.

Unfortunately, if a user touches down in an incorrect area, when they lift up they are also satisfying error 2--lifting up from an incorrect area.

Here's my code in a nutshell:

```
public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {
   float y = pSceneTouchEvent.getY();
   int dialog_count = 0;

   if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown() && y < 1000) {
     activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
         AlertDialog Code
         ..............
     }
    }
    dialog_count ++;
    Log.d("Dialog Count", "Count is " + dialog_count);
   } else if (dialog_count < 1 && pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp() && y > 105) {
    Log.d("Dialog Count", "Count is still " + dialog_count);
    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
       Second AlertDialog Code
       .................
   }
  }
 }
  return false;
 }
```

Now, my first log for `dialog_count` shows a value of 1. However when I lift up the second log shows a value of 0. Somehow this value is either getting reset or my Else statement just can't see the updated value of `dialog_count` because I get the second dialog popping on top of my first.

Any ideas?

Comment: This code is hard to follow because the number of `{` does not match the number of `}`. Please fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code initializes

```
int dialog_count = 0;
```

each time it runs.

To keep the value you saw the last time, make `dialog_count` an instance variable in the class.

Notice that you will be seeing two events, one for "down" and one for "up".

Comment: If you were referring to my comment, yes, I completely misread it. +1, good catch.

Comment: Moved it to the top of the class and that fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: So with If statements, the whole block is started over even if the first is satisfied? I don't know why I didn't just make it a class variable in the first place, and it works great now, but I just don't fully understand why it wasn't working before. Thanks again!

Comment: No, that is what I meant by *you will be seeing two events, one for "down" and one for "up"*. Two separate event arrive.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show only one then you need to use a flag to check if the user has touched down and then if you want not to show the touch up dialog just check from the flag. But the Touch down will always follow the Touch Up. You can use the Touch Move method if you want to show the dialog when the user has moved a bit.

Comment: The problem with this in my case would have been, if a user touches down in a correct area they could still touch up in an incorrect area and need that second dialog. If I used a touch down flag that would eliminate the possibility of triggering the touch up dialog when needed. My question didn't make it clear, but the user will be touching down then moving their finger. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, what you are trying to do

1. dialogCount is function local (garbage collected, after you exit the method). So it will be 0 on each new run of the method. (Make it private class variable).
2. If you are referring to your dialogCount in multiple threads, dialogCount must be thread safe, so use concurrent primitives - AtomicInteger

Comment: Presuming `onSceneTouchEvent` is called in response to an event on the EDT, then thread-safety is not an issue here.